# What would be the best way to use jammit and publish files on amazon S3?

Tags: capistrano, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, jammit

I'm using jammit to package the js and css files for a rails project. 
I would like now to upload the files to Amazon S3 and use CloudFront for the delivery.

What would be the best way to deal with new versions ?
My ideal solution would be to have a capistrano recipe to deal with it.

As anyone already done something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a capistrano task that triggers the copy to s3 after deploying.
You might use s3cmd as the command line tool for that.

Alternatively you could create a folder mounted by FuseOverAmazon, and configure it as the package_path in your jammit assets.yml. Make sure to run the rake task for generating the asset packages manually or in your deploy recipie.

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon